# MySQL multiple-part index not filtering data set

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one holding events that can happen at any point during the year, and the other connecting those to school years.  I can retrieve the corresponding school years, but the multiple-part index on the events table doesn't appear to be filtering the data set.

I have tried both of these, as well as flipping the order of the joined tables (in case MySQL's left-to-right index usage is coming into play), but the variations don't make a difference.

SELECT y.school_year FROM events e, years y WHERE e.yid = y.id AND e.year = y.year GROUP BY y.school_year ORDER BY y.school_year DESC

SELECT DISTINCT y.school_year FROM events e, years y WHERE e.yid = y.id AND e.year = y.year ORDER BY y.school_year DESC

EXPLAIN output:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key         key_len     ref             rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      e       index   meet_year       meet_year   9           NULL            486200  Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE      y       eq_ref  PRIMARY         PRIMARY     8           e.yid,e.year    1
```

Here is the relevant index on the events table which contains 486,200 rows:

```
Keyname     Type    Cardinality     Field
event_year  INDEX   978             yid, year
```

Shouldn't EXPLAIN be showing 978 rows, not all 486,200?  The query takes half a second to execute, which seems way too slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have no other filters and a GROUP BY, the query planner is deciding to do a full table scan instead. You could try this and see if the EXPLAIN output shows less rows being processed:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT y.school_year 
FROM years y
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT e.yid, e.year
    FROM events e
) e ON e.yid = y.id AND e.year = y.year
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I wondered if the GROUP BY was the issue, which is why I also tried it with just DISTINCT.  Your method produces a 0.0170 sec query (down from 0.5 sec) and a much more reasonable 979 rows scanned.  I hadn't considered a sub-select for the purpose, but that makes sense since there's no filtering needed on the events table.